# PCB layout, pitch width

Tags: pcb, design

What is the standard maximum copper thickness for minimum pitch size of a SMD component in a PCB?
For example, what will be the maximum copper thickness for a pitch of 0.65 mm? Or is there any standardized table for such comparison.

Comment: PLEASE DO NOT SHOUT in the title of your question.

Comment: I havent understood what you are trying to say. it will be helpful if u elaborate a little more as I am new here

Comment: Learn Netiquette for all caps

Comment: Width is often limited by thickness but some shops can do better.  Checkout Sierra cats who have loads of user help onsite

Comment: You have used BLOCK CAPITALS in your question title. That is known as "shouting" at us. Use normal text "PCB layout, pitch size".